# how Creating a xml sitemap in php (1000-1000)

Tags: php, xml-sitemap, sitemap.xml

I want to generate a dynamic sitemap in PHP similar to WordPress sitemap that includes items products, posts, and categories divided into 1000-1000.

1- How to create a sitemap for a PHP site?

2- How to divide the sitemap content into 1000-1000?

[image: 1]

Comment: You need to show you have made a good faith attempt and that you have done your research, otherwise it looks like you're asking for a tutorial or "do this for me" which are both off-topic. A [mre] is a good way to show this

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WordPress, You can use plugins like `Yoast SEO` to generate website maps.

Or there are also many online *Free site map generator*,such as https://ml-sitemaps.com ,  https://web-site-map.com and so on.

**Try to search on Google!**

Comment: i need generate sitemap in site by PHP code